# SQL - Better Performance vith a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, view

I'm running on SQL Server 2014, and have a `Customer` table related to a table with orders. The `Order` table has e.g 500.000 rows - 100.000 for each of 5 customers. So when looking for all orders for a specific date for a specific customer, the SQL would be

```
Select * 
from Orders 
Where idCustomer = 1 
  and OrderDate = '20160225'
```

This query should look through 500.000 records to find relevant orders.

Would it be better for performance to create 5 views, a view for each customer and then querying the view:

```
Select *
from View_Orders_Customer1 
Where OrderDate = '20160225'
```

Or do I have to create 5 tables `Order_Customer1`, `Order_Customer2` etc. - instead ??

Comment: Neither Views (standard views) nor multiple tables are the answer to your issue. An Index or two can massively help performance but, and it's a big but, it depends on how often the data is updated (or added to or deleted). If it's a test/dev database then look at Indexing. If it's a production database then be careful, indexing can speed selects but they can slow down updates/inserts/deletes.

Comment: Neither this nor that. 
You should simply create an index on the Orders table that will be composed of the `idCustomer` column and the `OrderDate` column.

Comment: Regular `views` don't do anything - they are fully expanded and source code of a `view` becomes part of the outer query. Just like there was no `view` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend create view for each customer .. but you can add Index in your table http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp

Also you can add Index on your view to enhance your select performance
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864(v=sql.105).aspx

I have table contains more than 700,000 records and applying indexing in table and view helped me very much

Comment: @henjensen if my answer solve your problem mark it as solved so other can use it .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For same data model, use same table(s). More than one table or view is not good design,

- You should look at execution plan, and create necessary indexes,
- After performance tuning with table indexes, you can use Indexed Views,
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.120).aspx